# How to make Windows batch file to copy directories?

Tags: windows, cmd

I am trying to create a Windows batch file that can copy a directory to another.

Note: The directory path must work for the current user as a variable.

I tried this and it didn't work:

```
SETLOCAL 
SET van=%USERNAME%
xcopy C:\Users\%van%\Desktop\Chabah\Pocket\Proxy C:\Users\%van%\Documents\iMacros\Macros
```

Comment: Define "didn't work."

Comment: @EJoshuaS error message "arguments number no valid"

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```
xcopy /E/Y C:\Users\%USERNAME%\Desktop\Chabah\Pocket\Proxy C:\Users\%USERNAME%\Documents\iMacros\Macros\
```

I added:

- \E to copy the entire directory
- \Y to overwrite without prompting
- a trailing\ to Macros to indicate it's writing a directory

Comment: To see all of the options, use `xcopy /?` at the command prompt. Even more with `robocopy /?`.

Comment: I think it would be better to use `%USERPROFILE%` instead of the path `C:\Users\%USERNAME%` twice in the command line above as the predefined environment variable `USERPROFILE` holds the complete path to the user's profile directory. And it is advisable to enclose both paths in double quotes as the user name could contain also a space character. And last parameter `/I` would be also good as explained in help of `xcopy`.